# How do I use powershell to send an email only if the script had to start an app pool?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that I use with task scheduler that very simply starts an app pool if one is stopped at the time the script runs:

```
Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where {$_.State -ne "Started"} | Restart-WebAppPool
```

This has worked great, however I need to have an email sent if an app pool has to be started, preferably with the name of the app pool in a list. I know I need to output the results to a variable, but I am having trouble finding the proper path to having it send if it has to start an app pool.

Any advice is very much appreciated, thanks!

I have been able to get Send-MailMessage to work for basic emails, I have not been successful specifying when to send based off results of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Foreach` to do multiple actions per pipeline object:

```sh
Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where {$_.State -ne "Started"} | ForEach-Object {

    # send an email
    Send-MailMessage -Subject "Restarted AppPool $($_.Name)" ## [other params]

    # and restart the app pool
    $_ | Restart-WebAppPool
  }
```